# Script/ Macro in Excel, by clicking on a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, events, mouse-click

There's something I want to do in Excel 2010. Specifically, I want to be able to make the open sheet load data from a text file, by clicking -important- on a cell of the current open worksheet.

So my specific needs are:

1. If it is possible in some way, to start a macro/script by clicking on a cell.

About the script/macro:

2. What would be the preferable, by your opinion, way of implementation.
3. And more specifically, how to automatically import the data needed, only by clicking, without having to continually specify the desirable .txt file each time, only 1 time at max, at start or by using a custom "initalization/configuration" file.

Comment: Just to clarify; why can't you use a button object?

Comment: Being an almost complete novice at excel and visual basic, it would be nice to see you express your thoughts in a proper answer :)

Comment: Would double-click be O.K.??

Comment: One click would be appreciated, but if it doesn't have that much of an impact on the core of the solution, you may go on with the idea and let me see what's beneficial.

Comment: I'm reading a 24-hour tutorial on Visual Basic, but the fastest I get the solution, the better. Thanks in advance for any interest!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very specific example that you can adapt to your needs.  Its a worksheet event macro that is triggered by double-clicking on cell **B9**:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Intersect(Target, Range("B9")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
Cancel = True
Dim TextLine As String
    Close #1
    Open "C:\TestFolder\test.txt" For Input As #1
    i = 1
    j = 0
    Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, TextLine
            j = j + 1
            Cells(i, j) = TextLine
        Loop
    Close #1
End Sub
```

The changes you will have to make:

1. the cell to double click is B9
2. the filespec of the text file to be opened
3. the destination for the imported data

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: That seems helpful. Would you mind pointing a way of trasnferring created macros to new excel files easily and a way to "automatically" expand the code to include custom cells? (I don't mind if I would need  to create a seperate application to achieve these) If you don't mind, I can also PM you and post the results of the overall try as a new self-answered question. Or if you think I should make a seperate question for each section, say it. Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: You can import/export chunks of VBA code directly from the VBE menu.

Comment: What you said was quite helpful. What I will say now might get confusing. Could adding vba code become a macro itself? I mean, I could start a "master macro", which would take some arguments into account and then add as many, and in the right form, chuncks of the above code as needed, in the respective number of buttons. If the answer is yes, then all I will need is a bit of experimenting.

Comment: What you propose is interesting.  I have never tried it myself..................but the topic is covered here:   http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbe.aspx

Comment: Question: Your solution adds a whole line in each cell. Is there any function that add the seperate words in seperate cells, words being seperated by space?

Answer (score 0):

If there is no pressing reason for having the cell-click be the activation then the simplest method would be to create a button object.

Go to your Developer tab and select Insert then select button from Active X controls
[image: ActiveXControls]

Next click and drag out the shape of your button, then right click it and select Proerties.

From here you can change things like the text displayed on the button and the the colour of the button. If you select Format Control when right clicking and go to Proerties you can set the box to not move and rezie when cells/rows/columns are changed.

Next right click on the button and select View Code
[image: View Code]

This will take you to the code window where you can insert your VBA. You're From there enter the rest of Gary's code from Dim TextLine down.

Finally go back to your Developer tab and deselct Design Mode
[image: Design Mode]

You can now test the button out. If you need to make any changes to it, or move it around, simply reselect Design Mode.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But for my case specifically, I need this to be activated by a cell-click. Plus I need to make an "application", where the number of buttons needed will be unknown, probably decided at the opening of the file, and I need it to be a "transferrable" feature, not file-specific. I belive the "cell" approach would be easier to fullfil these.

Comment: No worries, this of course was why I was asking for more info in the first place :)